# WAMP Not Showing Tree Structure Project Files

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit and WAMP 3.0.0

I have successfully installed WAMP and have Configured Virtual host. but when I click project names on WAMP homepage it is only runs the index page. I want to see all files in tree structure.
any solution Please

[httpd-vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDA2W.jpg)
 successfully added those entries in host file also

Comment: Those Virtual Hosts are not correctly configured. Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) It talks about WAMPServer 2.5 but everything still applies to WAMPServer 3

Comment: Also there is an update to WAMPServer 3.0.0 [V3.0.4 That can be found here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.4.exe/download)